# Why is quizEl returning error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx

I did a fetch api request then set the value of the question state to the array of objects from API but now when I am using the state it is returning undefined

```
import React from "react";

function App(props) {
  const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState()
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=18&difficulty=medium&type=multiple').then(res => res.json()).then(value => {
      setQuestion(value.results)
    })
  },
  [])
  
  const quizEl = question.map(q => {
    return <h3>{q.question}</h3>
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="question">
        {quizEl}

        <div className="options">
          <button className="btn">option1</button>
          <button className="btn">option2</button>
          <button className="btn">option3</button>
          <button className="btn">option4</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried doing it in useEffects and also directly into the JSX

Comment: You are not providing an initial state in `React.useState()` for `question` therefore it being undefined until the API response arrives.

Comment: the default state is empty so when trying to map it it just says it's `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an initial state for your `useState` :

```
import React from "react";

function App(props) {
  // Here you provide an empty array for your initial state
  // (before the api is even called and so before it responses)
  const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState([])
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=18&difficulty=medium&type=multiple').then(res => res.json()).then(value => {
      setQuestion(value.results)
    })
  },
  [])
  
  const quizEl = question.map(q => {
    return <h3>{q.question}</h3>
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="question">
        {quizEl}

        <div className="options">
          <button className="btn">option1</button>
          <button className="btn">option2</button>
          <button className="btn">option3</button>
          <button className="btn">option4</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for a bad question